# Getting Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF) (CWE ID 918) restTemplate.getForEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, veracode, ssrf

I am using `restTemplate` for synchronous inter-service communication in a microservices architecture.

When we completed `Veracode` scan, we are getting `Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF) (CWE ID 918)` in `getForEntity` method.

```
restTemplate.getForEntity(URL, Entity.class);
```

Not sure why I am getting this `SSRF` issue?.
What would be the possible fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by build the URL using UriComponents before using it in restTemplate.

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
  .scheme("http").host("www.yourdomain.com").path("/yourPath").build();
```

Please refer this link to use UriComponents https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder